# Ubuntu 12.04 lts won't boot after system crash + corrupt file system

Tags: boot, mount, fsck

Late the other night, Ubuntu crashed suddenly (wasn't doing anything unusual - just using firefox and audacity). I didn't catch the error message, and didn't think much of it - just went and rebooted - trying to boot the Linux drive from GRUB (I also have Windows on another HD) - it wouldn't load. Neither would the recovery option.

Booted from the Ubuntu 12.04 system disk, and used the "Try Ubuntu" option. Couldn't even mount the drive Ubuntu is located on, though it shows up in fdisk -l.

I ran `sudo fsck -t ext4 -f /dev/sdb1` from terminal and got this message:

```
JBD: Failed to read block at offset 8480
fsck.ext4: Input/output error while recovering ext3 journal of /dev/sdb1
/dev/sdb1: ***** FILE SYSTEM WAS MODIFIED *****
/dev/sdb1: ********** WARNING: Filesystem still has errors **********
```

This allowed me to at least mount the drive, but not access much or boot from it - always got an error saying it couldn't read file - kernel must be loaded first when I tried to boot.

Then I ran `sudo fsck -t ext4 -y /dev/sdb1` - and it was fixing a ton of errors overnight like this in pass one -

```
Inodes that were part of a corrupted orphan linked list found. Fix? yes
Inode 56885569 was part of the orphaned inode list. FIXED. There was around 100 of those fixed.
```

Went on to pass two and it was fixing a lot more errors...

```
Entry 'ksocket-ehah' in /tmp (9961473) has an incorrect filetype (was 2, should be 6). Fix? yes
```

`ehah` is my username on the system by the way.

A lot of those errors don't even show an entry name or directory location - just says Entry '...' in ??? and said its missing '..." in a directory Inode.

After pass two completed, it gave an error that said "resize inode not valid " and re-ran pass one. Not sure what happened after this point (I was just letting it run - the whole process took around 18 hours) - but the final result was -

```
/dev/sdb1: ***** FILE SYSTEM WAS MODIFIED ***** /dev/sdb1: 262033/121610240 files (0.6% non-contiguous), 45779164/486412288 blocks.
```

Still won't boot - and won't mount anymore when I'm using the Ubuntu live CD.

No backup. Any ideas how to get this working again, or at least save as much data as possible?

The drive was always unmounted when I was using the fsck command.

When I try to mount the drive from the terminal , I get:

```
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdb1,
missing codepage or helper program, or other error
In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
dmesg | tail or so
```

`fdisk -l` shows the following (sda1 is a seperate drive with Windows on it, that runs fine.)

```
Device Boot Start End Blocks Id System
/dev/sda1 * 63 2930255999 1465127968+ 7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT

Disk /dev/sdb: 2000.4 GB, 2000397852160 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 243201 cylinders, total 3907027055 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00003767

Device Boot Start End Blocks Id System
/dev/sdb1 * 2048 3891300351 1945649152 83 Linux
/dev/sdb2 3891302398 3907024895 7861249 5 Extended
Partition 2 does not start on physical sector boundary.
/dev/sdb5 3891302400 3907024895 7861248 82 Linux swap / Solaris
```

Answer (score 0):

Your filesystem is corrupt, I believe that you can't get data back (you should do backups).
You can try some "Deleted Files Recovery" programs, don't know if this will do anything. Seems like a reinstall for me, but I might be wrong.